# How to handle a request of quantitative benefit analysis from top management where only a qualitative statement can be made?

Tags: germany, project-management

Some months ago, I took over the project management (together with a collegue from engineering, my responsibility is the scope of operations) for a project from a colleague who had left. The project is intended to improve the consistency of the order processing process with regard to master data in SAP.

At the beginning of the project, great effects were envisioned and communicated to the top management, but now it has become clear that the implementation will take up a lot more capacity across all devisions and that the positive effects will remain rather moderate. The steering committee would now like to see a list of the positive effects of the project with concrete figures in order to compare these with the estimated person-hours for the project. However, the reliable estimation of the effects is only possible qualitatively (in the sense of positive, negative, strong or weak). Almost none of the project participants would be willing to commit themselves to concrete figures in their area. This is due to the fact that these effects are multifactorial and strongly dependent on the business situation and strategy.

**To make an example:**

In the area of purchasing, a declared effect is that the replenishment time should be reduced by a better forecast. However, this effect can only occur if the forecast actually improves and the corporate strategy allows inventories to be built up. In addition, a short replenishment time only has a positive effect if a near-time slot can be used in assembly at all. This list of influencing factors is not complete for reasons of brevity, but it already illustrates why the effect cannot be easily, reliably and seriously monetized.

Four times now, an evaluation has been presented to the steering committee, each time with the feedback that it was too general and not quantified enough. Despite the fact that in the meantime constrained scenarios (with many footnotes for safety) have been presented.

My dilemma is that I want to break this cycle of getting the same assignment over and over again without beeing able to meet the requirements. I can't make the estimate over the heads of the department representatives, firstly because they have to be backing it and secondly because I can't estimate it myself for each department. However, I have to present figures to the steering committee, even if I don't believe in them, because it seems impossible to estimate all influencing factors of the future correctly. Both my team and I are afraid of being pinned down to the reported effects in the future. If I don't refine the evaluation, however, I will incur the displeasure of the steering committee and receive the same assignment over and over again.

How can I satisfy the Steering Committee's requirement while keeping myself and my colleagues out of liability?

Comment: Is your goal here to keep your job, keep the project going, do the right thing for your employer or something else? Those goals may be mutually exclusive, but if you can't justify why you are doing the project, maybe it _should_ be stopped.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Stopping the project is not an option, as it is part of a group-wide project that will be implemented in any case. However, the steering committee of my plant is interested in some kind of ROI. I don't think that my job is at stake here, but to stand out negatively here will certainly make the future career path in the group more difficult.

Comment: The project ending may not be an option, but your position with it may since you cannot deliver what your bosses require - a schedule, which honestly is not that big of an ask. So the question of what do you want to achieve seems on point.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear, let me clarify: The project has a milestone plan and an effort estimate, both of which have been accepted by the steering committee and are reasonably consistent with the project's progress to date. So a schedule is not the problem. The problem is that I can't estimate the benefits in a clear amount. Since the project was imposed on me and everything else is going well, this is not a sufficient reason to hand over the project without making a bad impression. So my goal is to not lose my reputation in the company, both towards the top management and the project participants

Comment: It's a very delicate situation.  Do your best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a steering committee is demanding hard data to justify a project, that project is on the "kill this project list". Almost no large SAP project can be cost justified.
There are only three ways to handle this:

1. Lie (Not recommended)
2. Change the project from a "cost/benefit" type of project to a "strategic" project. A "strategic" project is one that must be done for company strategic reasons no matter what the cost/benefit analysis is. Many SAP projects fall into this category.
3. Bring in "worst case estimates" and "best case estimates" to show what could be the worst costs and possible best results. Since department representatives can't commit to a single benefit result, ask them to give worst case and best case estimates (which I suspect they will be more comfortable with doing). It is very likely that worst case estimates will show that the project is not worth doing.

Comment: Kind of like number 3 because it shows a range and not a single number to be pinned on to. On second thougt though it might lead to the same feedback as before: of beeing too generic...

Answer (score 4):

**Be open, be honest and stand your ground**

At the next steering committee meeting present the work you have done so far and the results you have gotten. "Sorry, but that's the best I can do. I don't know what else try. If you have specific alternative suggestions I'm happy to consider them but otherwise that's the best I can give you."

If you can, throw in a description of the main blocker. "I need full sign-off of the numbers from the department heads and they can't do that because the information that they would need simply isn't knowable at this time".

The question is a bit weird in the first place. The cost/benefit analysis should have happened BEFORE the project got approved. Doing it after it's already going only makes sense if there is new data AND some desire/willingness to make significant changes because of it.

Honestly, it sounds to me like someone up the food chain is getting cold feet and is trying to cover their rear-end and/or find a way to deflect blame when the promised benefits don't come in.

You have never promised any benefits, so you need stand up and say "Sorry, I cannot not back this promise and I won't be holding your bag for you if it goes sideways".

Comment: In theory, I entirely agree with this answer. In practice, this kind of message isn't always well-received by upper management even if it's what they need to hear so may still not have the desired effect of allowing the OP to not lose reputation.

Comment: @PhilipKendall: that's possible but if that's the way they feel, nothing you can say or do will  change it. If you are being setup as the fall-guy you are in damage control mode. I'd rather take some grumbling managers now than being blamed for a large project failure later.

Comment: "The cost/benefit analysis should have happened BEFORE the project got approved." -- It sounds to me like benefits were presented before, but basically faked, by the prior project manager. Now they're trying to fill in that gap.

Comment: This opinion is valid, however I'd never recommend saying, *Sorry, but that's the best I can do.* Find some phrasing that doesn't make it sound like you are giving up, or drawing a line in the sand against the committee. Something like, "I have been unable to do better in this area because department representatives seem reluctant to give firm numbers. Their objection is based on uncertainties in some areas, such as their perception that they may not be allowed to have inventories be built up. And without larger inventories, some expected benefits would not materialize."

Answer (score 0):

It is always interesting when you're answering directly to upper management in its various forms (steering committee in this case).

> At the beginning of the project, great effects were envisioned and communicated to the top management, but now it has become clear that the implementation will take up a lot more capacity across all [divisions] and that the positive effects will remain rather moderate.

You don't mention if a quantitative benefit analysis was proposed at or before the start of the project. Obviously someone is measuring something, because I see in your question "now it has become clear that... the positive effects will remain rather moderate".  And in your reply comment we know that, "The project has... an effort estimate."

Request (if you don't have them) the original cost, benefit, and effort analyses. The detailed versions.  The department specific versions - if available.

Go back to the department representatives with that original information, and ask each of them how the situation has changed.
If departments originally provided that information, then you'll get a lot of feedback about what has changed.  Get them to quantize the change, and use those numbers.

If that original information came from some SAP salesperson, it's a different story.  So, change your ask of the department representatives to be, "We need to explain this to the steering committee.  You know they love SAP... and while the SAP assumptions *might be valid worldwide* - in what ways do they not apply to **our** situation?  We will need some concrete details as examples."

Either way, in order to *not* limit your career

1. Don't blame the department reps. (Not directly & don't imply it)
2. Give the steering committee some numbers, even if those numbers are based on the original estimates.

Example of #2:
"The improved forecast of replenishment time will not be as much of a benefit as originally forecast. This is because a short replenishment time only has a positive effect when a near-time slot can be used in assembly. The department representatives have been hard pressed to estimate how often this would actually occur, given that we do not know how much the accuracy will increase. We concur with the department representative that the 'better forecast' will only be 50% as beneficial as originally specified."